# Is it possible to apply the image tag to the result of another image tag?

Tags: django, wagtail

I have a little question about the image tag of wagtail.

Is it possible to apply the image tag twice time on the same image in a concatenated manner?

For example:

```
{% image photo width-1500 as photo_scaled %}
{% image photo_scaled fill-400x300 as image %}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the template tag `image` (eg. `{% image photo width-1500 as photo_scaled %}`), you are generating an **image rendition**, not a new image. So you cannot then generate a new rendition from a rendition.

> A “Rendition” contains the information specific to the way you’ve requested to format the image using the resize-rule, i.e. dimensions and source URL. [Image Tag Docs](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.13.1/topics/images.html#more-control-over-the-img-tag)

However, in your question above, `fill-400x300` will produce the exact same rendition size/compression - irrelevant to the input image.

Comment: I understand, sorry I had missed this part of the docs. Thank you very much :-)